# Calculate Raster mean with gdal_calc - unexpected result

Tags: gdal, gdal-calc

I have in input a single band 2 axis tif raster (float32 values). Using `gdal_calc` I need to produce an output raster (same dimensions of input) that contains in every pixel the mean value of the whole input raster (to be used in other calculation) - basically a "uniform" raster. To do this I use:

```
gdal_calc.py    --calc="mean(A,dtype=float64)"  --type="Float32"    --overwrite --NoDataValue=-32768    --outfile   output.tif  -A  input.tif
```

Based on

```
gdalinfo -stats input.tif
```

I get a mean of 0.45 approx. So I was expecting an output.tif with this value for every pixel, but what I get is a different image (constant horizontally but different values vertically). I tried several numpy.mean parameters  (axis, keepdims) but nothing changed.

Any suggestion or work around?

Comment: this is probably due to streaming (memory handling per stripe). A workaround would be to use computestatistics and create a new band using the python wrapping of GDAL.

Answer (score 1):

try  `--calc="mean(A,dtype=float64,axis=0)"`